# IE8 `window.fn !== fn`

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Can someone explain this?  IE8

```
( function(){
    window.foo = function foo(){};
    console.log( window.foo === foo ); // false
}() );
```

Comment: Very good read on 'named function expressions', which is what you've got there: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to an IE bug, the named function expression creates a separate local `foo` variable with a separate copy of the function.

[More info](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#example_3_named_function_expression_creates_two_distinct_function_objects):

> ```
> var f = function g(){};
> f === g; // false
> ```
>
> This is where things are getting interesting. Or rather — completely nuts. Here we are seeing the dangers of having to deal with two distinct objects — augmenting one of them obviously does not modify the other one; This could be quite troublesome if you decided to employ, say, caching mechanism and store something in a property of f, then tried accessing it as a property of g, thinking that it is the same object you’re working with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've read that before but have never been hit by it until now.

Comment: Once again, javascript is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in correcting the issue, this will work.

```
( function(){
    var f = function foo(){};
    window.foo = f;
    alert( window.foo === f ); // false
}() );
```